# Does SciPy's fsolve support different solvers algorithms?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I am using `fsolve` function in SciPy to solve certain non linear equation system, and I have noticed that comparing the results with MATLAB's `fsolve` for the exact input and initial condition I am getting different outcomes. Therefore, I was wondering how I could try to achieve same results with SciPy's `fsolve` as those in MATLAB.

Currently I have configured `fsolve` in Matlab like this

```matlab
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter-detailed','PlotFcn',@optimplotfirstorderopt);
options.StepTolerance = 1e-14;
%options.OptimalityTolerance = 1e-14
options.FunctionTolerance = 1e-14;
options.MaxIterations = 100000;
options.MaxFunctionEvaluations = 400;
%     options.Diagnostics = 'on'
options.Algorithm = 'levenberg-marquardt';%'trust-region'%
fun= @solveTransmissionLineForGAndC;
```

Whereas I have configure `fsolve` in SciPy like this

```py
fsolve(self.CandGTransmissionLineDistributedE,[g0,c0],Yin,xtol=1e-14,maxfev= 100000,epsfcn=1e-14)
```

So, as an example, the output I get from both, MATLAB and SciPy, for same four inputs is

SciPy: `[0.0263397261951065,0.0255996001756125,0.0255996001756125,0.0248335970729323]`

MATLAB:
`[0.036897213114754,0.036897213114754,0.036897213114754,0.036897213114754,0.036897213114754]`

How can I select the solver algorithm (or how) in SciPy's `fsolve`?

EDIT: adding MWE

```
def WandG(GW,Zin):
    G,W = GW # define real variables to be used for the function

    R = (G**2)*(Zin.real - 0.1164) +(( 70e-12 * ( W/100 ) )**2)*( 2.9036155068866304e+16*(Zin.real - 0.1164) ) - G 

    I = (G**2)*( Zin.imag - 18.743998408378143 * (1-W/200) ) + (((W/100)*70e-12)**2)*( 2.9036155068866304e+16*(Zin.imag - 18.743998408378143 * (1-W/200)) ) + 170399985.53071037*(70e-12*(W/100) )

    return R,I

sol = optimize.root(WandG, [0.136879496, 47.04],(12.652884410928804+14.632724423763523j), jac=False, method='lm',tol=1e-14)
```

The solution using Scipy would be

```
sol.x[0] = 0.0795283512113496 # G
sol.x[1] = 36.53727146377749  # W
```

Whereas with MATLAB for the same initial conditions, solver and Zin, it returns, which I trust more since it resembles better to the final result of `W` which is `W=50`

```
G = 0.0794
W = 44.5234
```

Comment: `fsolve` is just a wrapper around MINPACK's hybrd method (a modified powell method). If you want to choose a specific method, use [root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root) instead. With `method="lm"` you choose the levenberg-marquardt algorithm.

Comment: Using this command `sol = optimize.root(self.WCandGTransmissionLineLumpedE, [self.initialGoCo[0],WCo],[Zin,WaterContent], jac=False, method='lm',tol=1e-14)` i see that `root` complains  with `The relative error between two consecutive iterates is at most 0.000000'`

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you'd provide a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @joni I have added the mwe, thanks!

Comment: I don't see any problem here with scipy's solution for you MWE... Check your equation system's function values for each solution and you'll see that the matlab one is wrong.